# No me imprime acentos en C

Tags: c

mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo que hacer una función que extraiga de un .txt datos a un registro y tiene que conservar las tildes. El tema es que cuando verifico que la función ande bien veo que no me imprime las tildes. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme estaría agradecido.
Ya he intentado con setlocale(LC_ALL, "Spanish"); SetConsoleCP(1252); y SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
Creo yo que el problema está en cómo extraigo la info del txt pero no me doy cuenta cómo arreglarlo o siquiera dónde está el problema
Este es el código que tengo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct _segui{
        int nro_seg;
        char nombre_seg[32];
        int dia_nac;
        int mes_nac;
        int anio_nac;
        int cant_seg;
        int cant_comp;
    }segui;

void CARGA( struct _segui *seguidor){
    FILE* Seguidores;
    Seguidores=fopen("seguidores.txt", "r"); //abro el archivo seguidores txt en mi archivo Seguidores
    if (Seguidores==NULL){                      //confirmo que lo haya podido abrir
        printf("Error al abrir el fichero\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    char linea[150];
    char nombre[32], nro_segu[32], dia_naci[32], mes_naci[32], anio_naci[32], cant_segu[32], cant_compa[32];
    int i=0;
    fscanf(Seguidores, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", nro_segu, nombre, dia_naci, mes_naci, anio_naci, cant_segu, cant_compa );
    (seguidor+i)->nro_seg=atoi(nro_segu);
    printf("%d\t",(seguidor+i)->nro_seg );
    strcpy((seguidor+i)->nombre_seg, nombre);
    printf("%s\n", (seguidor+i)->nombre_seg);
    i++;
    while(fgets(linea,150,Seguidores) != NULL){       //mientras que no llegue al final del archivo Seguidores hago lo siguiente
        fscanf(Seguidores, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", nro_segu, nombre, dia_naci, mes_naci, anio_naci, cant_segu, cant_compa );
        (seguidor+i)->nro_seg=atoi(nro_segu);
        printf("%d\t",(seguidor+i)->nro_seg );
        strcpy((seguidor+i)->nombre_seg, nombre);
        printf("%s\n", (seguidor+i)->nombre_seg);
        i++;
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    struct _segui seguidor[10000];
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Spanish"); // Cambiar locale - Suficiente para máquinas Linux
    SetConsoleCP(1252); // Cambiar STDIN -  Para máquinas Windows
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1252); // Cambiar STDOUT - Para máquinas Windows
    CARGA(seguidor);
    printf("%d\t %s", seguidor[3].nro_seg, seguidor[3].nombre_seg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la codificación del archivo de texto? ¿UTF-8?

Comment: Honestamente no tengo idea, cómo puedo verificar eso?

Comment: Puedes utilizar un editor de texto o código avanzado. Por ejemplo, visual studio code y notepad++ informan la codificación del archivo abierto en la barra de estado, en el inferior de la ventana. El bloc de notas de Windows 11 también es capaz de informarte algunas codificaciones.

Comment: Si, está en UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se quiere escribir texto con caracteres que no están en ASCII (de 7-bits, el de 8 es ASCII extendido) solo basta con que la codificación de la consola sea la misma que el texto.

En Windows puedes cambiar la codificación de salida de la consola con la función [`SetConsoleOutputCP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp). Para UTF-8 el código es el siguiente:

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
```

Puedes consultar otras codificaciones [aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers).

---

Otra opción es cambiar la codificación del texto con [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) y usar [`WriteConsoleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole):

```
std::string linea;

UINT codificacion_original = 65001; // UTF-8

DWORD largo = MultiByteToWideChar(codificacion_original, 0, linea.c_str(), linea.size(), 0, 0);

LPWSTR buffer = malloc(sizeof(WCHAR) * largo);
MultiByteToWideChar(codificacion_original, 0, linea.c_str(), linea.size(), buffer, largo);

WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), buffer, largo, 0, 0);
```

Las [funciones que terminan en W](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api) (wide) trabajan con Unicode (UTF-16). Así que `SetConsoleOutputCP` aparentemente no les afecta.

Más sobre [Unicode en Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-pages).

Comment: Si el rendimiento es importante, mejor reservar una porción grande de memoria e imprimir el texto en varias partes. No olvides liberar la memoria.